# Can't save polygon in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps polygon object:

```
var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737)
  ]
});
```

I'm trying to send it to MySQL db via jquery's AJAX:

```
$.post("savePolygon.php", {polygon: poly});
```

I get this error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'lat' of undefined
```

I've seen some other posts about saving polygons, and they all say to extract the latLng's from the poly's and save them in a db. When I do this though:

```
var latLngs = poly.getPath().getArray();
$.post("savePolygon.php", {polygon: latLngs});
```

I get the same error. It seems there is a function in array's prototype called 'lat'. I'd like to know how exactly can I extract those values and send them via AJAX, and also why do I get this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(`)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#encoding) to encode the path. This method returns a string, perfect for storing into a DB. For reuse decode the string by using  `google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath()`

Please note: the geometry-library isn't loaded by default,  you must load it by appending `&libraries=geometry` to the src of the maps-API-script.

To explain why you can't store the path directly(e.g. as JSON):
when you store the path(array), which contains the LatLng's, you will lose the prototype of the LatLng's, which is  essential because it defines the methods for retrieving the properties(`lat()` and `lng()` )

Comment: Can you encode it using encodePath() and decode it on server side?

Comment: No, you can store the encoded polygon in a DB and decode it on clientside later when needed

Comment: And how do you proceed for a rectangle instead of a polygon ?

Comment: a rectangle is defined by 2 points(southwest and northeast). You may either store these 2 points or create a polygon from the rectangle by using northeast, southeast, southwest and northwest as path and store this path encoded.

Comment: For my part I send myrectangle.getBounds to a php script, pick up it with $_POST and store it. But I don't know how to proceed in the other way. Fetching ok but under which form to transmit it to the javascript script and how to use it...