# JSON string changes its keys for Google MAPS API v3

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, polygon, latitude-longitude

I've seen this question a few times already on here but the responses aren't quite applicable to my case.

I am using a google.maps.Polygon object to save bounds that is drawn on a map.

Later I am using the "getPath" method and I add this to a Json string.

The JSON string is always different. Sometimes I can grab the polygon corners by:

thisShape.data.b[i].kb
thisShape.data.b[i].lb

other times by

thisShape.data.b[i].Qa
thisShape.data.b[i].Ra

etc.

It seems over time, the key for the Json string changes. However I am not responsible what the Google Api returns as far the Polygon object goes.

Is there a way to grab the longtitute and latitude without knowing the key?
Any ideas how to loop through my polygons without fear that it'll break in a few weeks?

Many thanks

---

Suppose you have a method called "SavePolygonData" that, among other things, creates a Json string like this:

```
var allData = {};
    $("div.shapes").each(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var type  = id.split('_')[0];
      var feature = MapToolbar.features[type+'Tab'][id];
      var vertices = feature.getPath();
      allData[id] = { color: feature.fillColor, data: vertices};
    });
    var allDataJson = JSON.stringify(allData);
```

and then later another method that reads the json string somewhere else like this:

```
for (var polyId in allData) {
    if (allData.hasOwnProperty(polyId)) {
      var thisShape = allData[polyId];
      var color = thisShape.color;
      var vertices=new Array();

      for ( var i=0; i<thisShape.data.b.length; ++i )
      {
        var coordX = thisShape.data.b[i].kb; //Problem here
        var coordY = thisShape.data.b[i].lb; //Problem here
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(coordX, coordY);
        vertices[i] = point;
      }
      var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: color,
        paths: vertices
      });
      poly.setMap(map);  
    }
```

I can't use the getLat() methods on the json string because obviously it only contains strings. Instead I have to create a new data structure for my "data" variable that contains processed data instead of feature.getPath().

That's what I need help with. What is the structure of that new data structure?

I have noticed there is the google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath() method.
But I need to be able to decode it in server side.

Comment: you mean you are grabbing data from minimized code? You should avoid that

Comment: I am  including http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js and that's the only external library which appears to be minimized. None of my code is minimized and as far as I know we don't have any control over the api structure that google provides

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't save polygon in google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137577/cant-save-polygon-in-google-maps)

Comment: oh that looks very promising

Comment: but I wouldn't be able to decode the string in server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your `SavePolygonData` example code is that you are trying to use the vertices data directly in your JSON object. Instead, you need to use the documented methods to get the latitude and longitude values from the vertex array and serialize those.

To fix it, you can change this code:

```
var vertices = feature.getPath();
allData[id] = { color: feature.fillColor, data: vertices};
```

to:

```
var vertices = getLatLngVertices( feature.getPath() );
allData[id] = { color: feature.fillColor, data: vertices };
```

and elsewhere define this function:

```
function getLatLngVertices( path ) {
    var pathArray = path.getArray();
    var vertices = [];
    for( var i = 0, n = pathArray.length;  i < n;  i++ ) {
        var latLng = pathArray[i];
        vertices.push({ lat: latLng.lat(), lng: latLng.lng() });
    }
    return vertices;
}
```

Now in your code that parses this JSON you can use:

```
var data = thisShape.data;
for( var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; ++i ) {
    var point = data[i];
    vertices[i] = new google.maps.LatLng( point.lat, point.lng );
  }
```

Comment: Oh!! I'll try that and let you know very shortly!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `getPath()` returns an `MVCArray` of `LatLng`, from which you are supposed to extract latitude and longitude by calling the `lat()` and `lng()` methods, not by directly accessing properties. If it were possible in JavaScript, these properties would have been declared `private`. But the same applies to the `MVCArray`, for which you have the choice of looping over with `forEach()`, or, if are not at ease with lambda functions yet, with `getAt()`, using the result of `getLength()` as guard:

```
polygon.getPath().forEach(function(latLng, idx) {
   var lat = latLng.lat();
   var lng = latLng.lng();
   // do something
});
```

or

```
var path = polygon.getPath();
var len = path.getLength();
for (var idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
   var latLng = path.getAt(idx);
   var lat = latLng.lat();
   var lng = latLng.lng();
   // do something
}
```

These examples are OK if the polygon consists of only one path. If not, you will have to loop over paths too.

Comment: This is what they suggest in the other answers that are similar but I am not sure I can use it, not without changing my method entirely. I'll elaborate in my question

Comment: @Nick: ok, now I see that your question is a bit different - unfortunately I don't have the time to elaborate on your code :-( - You should follow the link of Dr.Molle, though